# ImportJSON payload POST BODY

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use ImportJSON to interact with API and GOOGLE SHEETS, the task was to write in a body query.

```
{
  "reportType": "SALES",
  "groupByRowFields": [
    "FiscalChequeNumber",
    "OpenDate.Typed"
  ],
  "groupByColFields": [],
  "aggregateFields": [
    "DishDiscountSumInt"
  ],
  "filters": {
    "OpenDate.Typed": {
      "filterType": "DateRange",
      "periodType": "CUSTOM",
      "from": "2023-02-01",
      "to": "2023-02-20",
      "includeLow": true,
      "includeHigh": false
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to edit the code, but my technical knowledge is not enough and this is what I got:

```
function ImportJSONPayload(url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var fetchOptions = {"method": "POST", payload: {
    "reportType": "SALES",
    "groupByRowFields": {
        "FiscalChequeNumber", "OpenDate.Typed"
    },
    "aggregateFields": "DishDiscountSumInt",
    "filters": {
        "OpenDate.Typed": {
            "filterType": "DateRange",
            "periodType": "CUSTOM",
            "from": "2023-02-01",
            "to": "2023-02-20",
            "includeLow": "true",
            "includeHigh": "false"
        }
    }
}};
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

But unfortunately, nothing works.
I tried reading the technical documentation, but I do not understand it.
Can you help me?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `But unfortunately, nothing works.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script? By the way, I think that `"groupByRowFields": {"FiscalChequeNumber", "OpenDate.Typed"}` is not correct. From your above request body, is it `"groupByRowFields": ["FiscalChequeNumber","OpenDate.Typed"]`?

Comment: `{
  "reportType": "SALES",
  "groupByRowFields": [
    "FiscalChequeNumber",
    "OpenDate.Typed"
  ],
  "groupByColFields": [],
  "aggregateFields": [
    "DishDiscountSumInt"
  ],
  "filters": {
    "OpenDate.Typed": {
      "filterType": "DateRange",
      "periodType": "CUSTOM",
      "from": "2023-02-01",
      "to": "2023-02-20",
      "includeLow": true,
      "includeHigh": false
    }
  }
}`
- This is the body of my request
I use - https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON for connect api and google sheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the current issue of your script.

Comment: @Tanaike 
http://api-delivery.iiko.ru:8080/resto/api/v2/reports/olap?&key=ad6dfd60-78f4-32fa-c7fe-31f49ae99294 - thats url of my api

Comment: @Tanaike I need to write code so that I can do the import of json in my googlesheet, I wrote the body of the request and above wrote a link to the request itself.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.